# How do I use a shorter audio as the background for the longer one?

Tags: background

I have two audio files, one is 41:27 long and the other is 01:31 long named `0909.mp3`.

[image]

I'm trying to use `0909.mp3` as the background for the longer one with [ocenaudio](https://www.ocenaudio.com/).

I tried Paste Special | Overlap, From File

[image]

However, the background only covers 01:31 long.

[image]

I used some kind of a workaround, that is, Paste Special | Insert, to generate a longer audio file over and over again. It worked.

I'd just like to know if there is an easier way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In professional editors, no, there's no simple way to do this as it's not something which crops up a lot. But if it did, we'd most likely use a multichannel sequencer to easily repeat and manipulate the shorter audio clip in it's own sequencer channel.

There are other ways to do it, like through temporal effects like a delay line, but I think you're asking purely for a basic editing method.

I don't know that app, but I'd just edit the short one, copy it and keep pasting it to the end of the waveform, then trim, so it's the same length as the longer one (and fade out if necessary), then save it and mix it ("overlap") with the longer one. I think this is similar to what you did.

If you want silence in between the short copies, just add it in before you fill out the time with copy-paste. Same, if you want it to be relatively quieter or louder in the mix, just adjust the level before mixing. You may also need to adjust the amplitude of the mixed waveform.

In professional software, you might find a [macro creator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_recorder) or some other automation tool, so if you do this a lot, you can quickly create an automation sequence, which you can then run with the push of a button if you wish. For any repetitive task, big or small, you can usually automate it quite quickly and intelligently with these tools.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your overlapping audio (assuming they are overlapping and not replacing), use a 'Crossfade' or 'x-fade' function on the joins - this effectively turns down the volume on the first while turning up the volume on the second.

Comment: I think they're asking about repeating the shorter audio. Unless I read it wrong lol.

Comment: Yes they are - but they want to stop it sounding like it's chopped up - thus crossfading between the repeated clips

Comment: Having re-read it - they may also be asking about shortcuts for repeating the audio clip over an amount of time - This is surely dependent on the audio tool they are using.

Comment: Yeah, I had to read it a few times, but that's the kind of answer I gave, more general ways to repeat a short clip really.

Comment: I'm going to give your answer a +1 in that case! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly easy one - you need "[Paulstretch](http://hypermammut.sourceforge.net/paulstretch/)". This will allow you to stretch the audio to the right length.